# save image and videos within the app iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, save, nsdata

I want users to save the picked image and video within the app. So I wanted to know what is the best. Should i convert the picked images and videos to NSData and save in **Core data**? I search everywhere and everyone recommend to use **Documents Folder** to save images and videos because coredata is slower. I just started learning CoreData so I don't have much knowledge about it. Here is what I have come up.

> Users pick the image or video -> App Saves it to documents folder -> Using coredata, application stores the filepath as string to access the image or video. (and User can backup anytime using icloud)

and Users can access those files in their other devices using iCloud. Please explain me if I'm incorrect or if you have better alternative or the question is wrong in any way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've done both ways and for me it's just a matter of how to use the database. If you'd like to to be able to backup the database and share with other, I would recommend storing files in CoreData as NSData. If it's just a local database it might be easier to store URL's to images stored on disk.

When you setup a Binery field in CoreData you can optionally select "Allows External Storage" which basically store the file on disk for you, but you can load it from the databas as if it was stored in the db. This is what I use most for images.

With this option, it is easy to create a zip file of the database and all binary files connected to it and also easy to unzip it to make a restore of the database.

Comment: I don't really know. Since you don't control where CoreData stores the data to 100 % I guess it might be slower to store data in a binary field than just storing a string. I haven't had a problem with that yet anyway. My database stores about 1600 images.